# How can I enable ibus's input popup?

Tags: special-characters, input-method, ibus

I'm trying to get ibus's popup selection to work. I followed the instructions in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus), by installing the `ibus` and `ibus-libpinyin` packages.

ibus appears to partially work. `ibus-setup` works fine, and I can select inputs. In my text editor, I can then switch between English and (say) Arabic. Input changes as expected. However, after switching to Chinese Pinyin, text just appears as normal, with no pop-up appearing.

All packages are up-to-date.

- KDE Plasma 5.7.3-1
- ibus 1.5.14-1
- ibus-qt 1.3.3-6
- ibus-libpinyin 1.7.92-1
- libpinyin 1.5.92-1

(Previously posted on the [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215818) with no reply.)

### EDIT

I recently upgraded some of these packages, but I still am having this problem.

- KDE Plasma 5.7.4-2
- libpinyin 1.6.0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Plasma_5), I added `export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus` to `~/.xprofile`, which fixed it. I was initially thrown, because "normal" ibus input worked without this fix. In any case, I've edited the wiki to be a little clearer.